# Within the same batch file, get the process id of the program I just launched

Tags: python, batch-file, wmic

In a batch file, I am calling a python script, and then I want to get the process id of the process I just launched.  I am using something like this:

```
@start /b pythonw pycpoint.py %* >../pycpoint.log 2>&1 
@start /b wmic process where "CommandLine like 'pythonw%%pycpoint%%'" get ProcessID > winPID.txt
```

However, the winPID.txt file never gets created. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I launch python in a terminal, then open another terminal and use pgrep :

```
ps -ef | pgrep python
```

Is this what you need ? (or the python ID : `os.getpid()` )